# Can not run Jupyter with powershell

Tags: python, powershell, jupyter

I can not run Jupyter even though I install it. [image].

I tried even, to [image]but in the end, it does not work. How can I start it now? It is possible that I have on Windows an OneDrive Path? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. When python or any other language is stored in a Onedrive path, it wont be accessible from the pc. It will need to be stored in the C drive for it to be accessible. I would re install Jupyter notebook and python and try again.
This time install python in your c drive as well as
Jupyter notebooks